# Add default value to datatype array in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to create a field which is datatype of Array through migration and it did got updated in schema.rb file.

However my main goal was to give fixed value to this field (i-e Array), which is not going to change in future. Kind of static value.

I applied this method to create a field.

```
rails generate migration Store_detailsToAdmin store_details:string
```

**Admin.rb file.**

```
serialize :store_details, Array
rake db:migrate
```

Can anyone help me have default and fixed values on this column?

Comment: Any idea how we suppose to do it ? @Gabbar

Comment: Can you try given solution below, hopefully this should help you . let me know for any further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Set default value as "xyz"

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  serialize : store_details, Array
  after_initialize -> { self. store_details.blank? ? self. store_details.push('xyz') : self. store_details }
end
```

Get default value of it if array is blank

```
admin.store_details => ["xyz"]
```

Add another value in it

```
admin.store_details.push("abc")
admin.save
admin.store_details => ["xyz", "abc"]
```